# Valid login won't open link

Tags: javascript, validation

I have pieced together this login form with a Javascript credential validator. For testing verification I have set the login to be Ryan for the username and ryan1234 for the password.  When credentials are valid the user should be redirected to Facebook.  But, it's not working.  The credentials validate properly, but the window.location attribute sends to a broken location?

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}


var attempt = 3;

function validate() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == "Ryan" && password == "ryan1234") {
    alert("Login successfully");
    window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/"; // Redirecting to other page.
    return false;
  } else {
    attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
    alert("You have left " + attempt + " attempt;");
    // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
    if (attempt == 0) {
      document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="id01" class="modal">

  <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="container-modal">
      <label><b>Username</b>
      </label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" id="username" required>

      <label><b>Password</b>
      </label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="password" required>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Remember me
    </div>

    <div class="container-modal" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/"; // Redirecting to other page.

Isn't what you want... It should be window.location.href

Like this:
window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/"; // Redirecting to other page.

Comment: That makes sense but it wasn't successful, which leads me to believe that it is an issue with codepen which is where I have built it, and not your correction.  Do you know where I can test this code properly?

Comment: Maybe a virtual machine (try hosting a virtual webserver locally) or you could try a free hosting site. Those would be my best guesses (Unless you have your own domain, then that would be a good place to do it...). Just remember: Google is your friend...